# Is default '\n' line terminator can be changed?

Tags: matlab, serialization, serial-port, terminator

Is default '\n' Matlab line terminator can be changed? Can I use ',' instead of '\n'? Because the serial port that will be reading it is programmed to terminate when ',' is read.Is it possible? 
Any answers are highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you what you will read via serial port? A output file? The output of a simulink simulation? Where exactly do you need to have the line delimiter changed?

Comment: @ben A string with 11 char will be read. Specifically, arduino will be the one reading the string from Matlab.

Comment: @Van So in that case why do you need a line terminator at all? Just feed a 1D string in and place the commas where you need them.

Comment: @Dan I need a line terminator so that arduino will stop reading if it detects comma. Arduino might be reading the default terminator ('\n') of Matlab and arduino will consider it as a part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

use eg:

```
ser = serial('COM1');   % establish connection between Matlab and COM1

set(ser, 'Terminator', 'CR'); % set communication string to end on ASCII 13
```

and replace `'CR'` with `','`

See
http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/ceverba1/Class/e5/E5MatlabExamples.html
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/terminator.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple string in matlab is not terminated by \n or \0 since it is a simple array of chars, as seen here:

```
>> a = string('Hello World')
Warning: string is obsolete and will be discontinued.
         Use char instead. 

a =

Hello World

>> double(a)

ans =

    72   101   108   108   111    32    87   111   114   108   100
```

to add a \0 to the end simply use:

```
>> a(end+1)=0;
>> a

a =

Hello World 

>> double(a) %the zero is there, but not printable as seen here

ans =

    72   101   108   108   111    32    87   111   114   108   100     0
```